# ssh jump host option for some reason does not work

Tags: ssh, login, proxy

I'm trying to utilize ssh's jump host option but for some reason it does not work, I get:

```
$ ssh -J user1@host1 user2@target
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: invalid format
$ ssh -J user1@host1:22 user2@target:22
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

and I'm wondering why, I can login over ssh from user-notebook to host1 and then from host1 to target just fine. I have all keys setup too. I'm puzzled, what am I missing?

After adding `-v`, I can observe the following:

```
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 39: \033[?25h\033[?7hSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: invalid format
debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for target port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 1.
```

Note that I can connect fine to `target` with `ssh -J user1@host1 user2@target` from other hosts on the LAN but only this one doesn't seem to be able to connect.

When I change the line to `ssh -J user1@host1:22 user2@target:22 -v`, I get the following:

```
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Remote: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

What is it trying to do with `port 65535`?
I also ssh-ed to `host1` and did a:

```
netcat target 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

after the `touch ~/.hushlogin`, adding more `-v`s, with `-vvv` appended I get;

```
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 39: \033[?25h\033[?7hSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: invalid format
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for ghnvm port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for ghnvm port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536 (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 4/5/-1 sock -1 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 1.
```

Even `ssh -oProxyCommand='ssh -p22 user1@host1 -W %h:%p' -p22 user2@target` would return:

```
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: invalid format
```

Comment: 1. add at least one `-v` option for verbose output.   2. check your ~/.ssh/config on host1.  3. just a wild stab in the dark, but does it work after first running `ssh user1@host1 touch ~/.hushlogin` to suppress motd and all the other login-related noise from host1?

Comment: @cas I've added `-vvv` and pasted the ouput above, do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Does your jump-host (`host1`) output a custom text banner when you connect to it? If so, this text may confuse the local `ssh` which does not expect it.

Comment: can you ssh into host1 and then run `ssh target`?    i.e. does it work without using `-J`?

Comment: also, check your `/etc/issue`, `/etc/issue.net`, and `/etc/motd` on both host1 and target.   also `grep -i banner /etc/ssh/sshd_config` on them to see if they're configured for a Banner file.   The ssh error seems to be complaining about the Escape codes on banner line 39.  AFAICT, `\033[?25h\033[?7h` are escape codes to make the cursor visible and then to set autowrap on.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to check your ~/.ssh/config (and the defaults in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) on  your workstation and on host1 to see if there's some broken config for connecting to "target".     And look for `proxy.*command` in the ssh verbose output (redirect stderr from `ssh -vvv` to a log file so you can grep it).

Comment: BTW, using a high port like 65535 on the loopback interface (on the intermediate/jump host) is normal when proxying a ssh connection.

Comment: Sometimes the user's shell startup files (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) may interfere too, if they output a lot of crap for login shells. Check this on `host1`.

Comment: first of all, the form `ssh user@host:22` is not supported by ssh. You need `ssh -p22 user@host` (however `-J user@host:22` is valid)

Comment: @basin fair enoigh, i tried with `-p22` also but got the same result

Comment: Try `ssh -oProxyCommand='ssh -p22 user1@host1 -W %h:%p' -p22 user2@target`  instead of `-J`

Comment: @basin I tried that too and added the result to the bottom of my OP above

Comment: Same issue here, did you ever get it resolved?