# ssh jump fail abou banner invalid characters

Tags: debian, ssh

Updated `sshd` journal on both `jumphost` and `jumptarget`

---

Full logs are too long to be pasted. uploaded to [gist](https://gist.github.com/HernandoR/fac7792de5cc97af18193dd1237dc707)

three files are logs that :

Local -> Jumpper -> Debian by `ssh -j`

Local -> Jumpper -> Debian by `ssh Debian`

Local -> Jumpper by `ssh jumpper`

Jumper -> Debian by `ssh 10.10.10.3`

FYI: During this time, the IP address was re-planned `10.10.1.3 -> 10.10.10.3`, and a domain was added in the `hosts`. These shouldn't have any effect on the problem.

---

A similar problem is [SSH ProxyJump on macOS Catalina is not working](https://superuser.com/q/1510997). but the answer doesn't solve my case

I'm configuring ssh jump with the following configures:

```
Host Jumper
    HostName domainName
    User username
    Port 1234

Host Debian
    HostName 10.10.1.3
    User username
    Port 22
    ProxyJump Jumper
```

The result of `ssh Debian -vvv` is

```
...
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: \033(B\033[mSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
...
```

it shows OpenSSH, so I think the port should be correct

`ssh Jumper` is fine, and manully `ssh 10.10.1.3` on jumper is also fine.

Comment: I have found similar(?) questions: [*ssh jump host option for some reason does not work*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/656631/108618), [*SSH ProxyJump on macOS Catalina is not working*](https://superuser.com/q/1510997/432690). I don't know how similar each one is to yours because you posted only a tiny fragment of the verbose output (please [edit] if you want to improve). The latter question is answered, the answer is upvoted, but probably it won't help you (and frankly I have no idea how the bug the answer talks about could cause problems with the banner).

Comment: What are the versions of OpenSSH on all three machines?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The latter one is exactly my problem here, and truly not solving.

Comment: @user4556274 local host is a Macos at `OpenSSH_9.0p1`. Others are `OpenSSH_9.2p2`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add this relevant information there. The point is we (including you, I bet) want potential answerers to easily get the whole picture from the question alone, without any need to patch the question by seeking information in comments. Help them help you.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

At the first glance, I've been misslead by the keyword "banner" and the ANSI sequence. I do not delete but update this answer to preserve the helpful comments below.
Please regard this answer as a comment.

---

As *roaima* pointed out the `Banner` defined in `sshd_config` gets displayed at the beginning of the authentication, but your debug message is a result of kex-exchange that is done just before auth.

Also check *Kamil Maciorowski*, linked [hint](https://serverfault.com/questions/216801/prevent-ssh-from-advertising-its-version-number/767445#767445). — The tested string is part of the compiled code.

---

To find out more please activate at least `debug level 1` by changing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
LogLevel DEBUG1
```

- Restart your sshd by `systemctl restart sshd`
- Note that at Debian any settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` will take precedence over those in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (the first match takes control).

Of interest are these entries and their neighbours:

File: `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Sep 17 01:03:43 lamp sshd[1861]: Connection from 192.168.0.1 port 43854 on 192.168.0.2 port 22 rdomain ""
Sep 17 01:03:43 lamp sshd[1861]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
Sep 17 01:03:43 lamp sshd[1861]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
Sep 17 01:03:43 lamp sshd[1861]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
```

- Please do retrieve this at the JumpHost and the Destination Host (Debian) for ***the same connection attempt*** and update your question by the log results.
- Also add the related output of localhost using `ssh Debian -vvv` (more than just the error to see the context)
- It might be useful to also add the log of a ssh to the JumpHost itself, if there's a difference.
- Same optional interest to the ssh connection JumpHost > Destination Host

*Awaiting the results ...*

---

Regarding the above, the point that the match for `OpenSSH*` is searched the relevance of some preceding *"ANSI escape codes with typos"* reduces to *"some garbage that must not be there"*.

---

Your banner line contains a typo: Should be `[` in `\033(B`, but not not `(`.

```
# Your line:
\033(B\033[mSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2

# Fixed line:
\033[B\033[mSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2

\033[B    # tells "Move Cursor down" 
\033[m    # reset the ANSI colors
```

*Part of the original answer, but most likely not the solution for the question (see above):*

Configure the banner of OpenSSH Server

The file is configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`:

```
Banner FileName
```

*Did you find such an entry and the configured file?*

Disable the banner by `Banner none`  (and restart the `sshd`).

This has to be checked at both involved `sshd`: the JumpHost and the destination.

Comment: How does the banner get printed before the protocol identification string?

Comment: should it be edited at `localhost` or `Jumper` or `Debian` ?; I have tried disable it on `Jumper` and `Debian`, but the output does not change.

Comment: @Leo I think this answer is wrong. These are two different banners. `Banner` defines a custom banner while the problematic banner is the one that carries the version of SSH on the server. AFAIK the admin of the server cannot easily modify it. [`DebianBanner no` is what the admin can do](https://serverfault.com/a/767445/1044055) but I don't expect this to solve your problem either.

Comment: @roaima : You are right, I've been misslead by the keyword "banner" and the ANSI sequence. Updated the answer.